# Url action in cshtml doesnt render the correct URL it goes to the another action in the same control, when inspecting elements shows the correct href

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

this is my anchor tag, where "SubmitCart" is action but the URL goes to "GetItemsInCart", which is another action in the same controller. Even in the browser if I try to go to /SubmitCart it redirects me to "GetItemsInCart"

```html
<a href='@Url.Action("SubmitCart","ShoppingCart")' class="btn btn-primary">Checkout and View Receipt</a>
```

ShoppingCart Controller:

```cs
[Route("SubmitCart")]
public IActionResult SubmitCart()
{
    return RedirectToAction("ViewReceipt");
}

[Route("GetItemsInCart")]
public IActionResult GetItemsInCart()
{
    return View("Cart", products);
}
```

My default route setup:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I am new to asp.net core please help

Comment: Would you kindly add your `Full Controller Class`.

Comment: Hello is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Asp.net Core MVC` other than `Asp.net Web API` just get rid of `[Route("SubmitCart")]` `annotation` it will work as expected.

> **Note:** Point to remember when you use Route like this `[Route("SubmitCart")]` it will override your `routes.MapRoute` config
> as a result you are getting the error.

Like this way:

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  
   //[Route("SubmitCart")]
    public IActionResult SubmitCart()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

 //  [Route("SubmitCart")]
    public IActionResult GetItemsInCart()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
  }
```

**Client Side:**

```
<h2>GetItemsInCart</h2>

<a href='@Url.Action("SubmitCart","Home")' class="btn btn-primary">Checkout and View Receipt</a>
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="SubmitCart">Checkout and View Receipt</a>
```

> **Note:** Your `routes.MapRoute` config for `Asp.net MVC` seems alright. I have attached another way of `HTML` which you can hit controller.

Output: I have hitted both on URL and Button works as expected. See here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope It will help you. Let me know if you are still having this problem.